# I have a problem with google sheets script on smartphone

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wrote a simple code that should collect data from several cells in a Google Sheet and save them to another sheet. However, when I tested it on Windows, it worked fine, but now I'm testing it on a smartphone, and everything works until it's time to select a specific cell to make it active, and then it breaks.

```
function savedate() {
  let ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  let transWS = ss.getSheetByName("Трансфер")
  let textWS = ss.getSheetByName("текст")
  let sapWS = ss.getSheetByName("за САП")

  
let fieldRange = ["a4","b2","c2","b4"]

let fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => transWS.getRange(f).getValue())
transWS.getRange("a5:d6").protect();
let numCell = textWS.getRange("b2")
let num = numCell.getValue()
fieldValues.unshift(num)
sapWS.appendRow(fieldValues)
transWS.appendRow(fieldValues)

numCell.setValue(num+1)

 transWS.getRange("b4").clearContent();
 
 transWS.setActiveCell("b4");
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Please help.